# how to configure email address on submit button in html contact form

Tags: php, html

I am unable to configure my email address on the submit button in this piece of code:

```
<div id="contact" class="spacer">

<div class="container contactform center">
<h2 class="text-center  wowload fadeInUp">Get in touch with us</h2>
  <div class="row wowload fadeInLeftBig">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-xs-12">
        <form class="cmxform" id="commentForm" method="post" action="email.php">
        <fieldset>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="csubject" name="subject" minlength="2" type="text" required>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" id="cemail" type="email" name="email" required>
        <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Message" id="ccomment" name="comment" required></textarea>
        <input class="submit  btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I tried linking it to a php page (email.php), but it says server error. I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Well, does the file email.php exist in the same directory as the file above?

Comment: Yes it is in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email you need the mail() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

With your code you need to name the submit like `name="submit"` then inside action.php file you have to write something like this (or inside the same php where you have this code):

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
//Remember to do input validations
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$from = $_POST["email"];
$comment = $_POST["comment"];
$body = "User with email $from send the next comment: $comment";


//then here you set your email

$to = "myemail@email.com"; //change this
mail($to,$subject,$body);
}
```

This is only to explain some basic usage and set the variables you need, I advice you read also PHPmailer class